# final code of my first winform application

Tags: c#, beginner, winforms

I am learning .NET for about a month now ..and i am practicing by making a simple WinForms project ..now almost my WinForms is completed ..i need to gather your suggestion on how my progress is going and the code is efficient or not , kindly review this below code and share you valuable suggestions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace QCIP
{
    public partial class FormNewEntry : Form
    {
        readonly string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;

        public FormNewEntry()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            get_items();
        }

        private void FormNewEntry_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'sQCDataDataSet.IP_Spools' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.iP_SpoolsTableAdapter.Fill(this.sQCDataDataSet.IP_Spools);
            this.iP_SpoolsBindingSource.AddNew();
           // f2.fo = spoolIdTextBox.Text;

        }
        void get_items()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            String query = "select * from RejReason";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                string item_names = dr.GetString(1);
                rejectReason1ComboBox.Items.Add(item_names);
                rejectReason2ComboBox.Items.Add(item_names);
                rejectReason3ComboBox.Items.Add(item_names);
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        private void btnsave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                String msg = "Confirm Save?";
                String caption = "Save Record";
                MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
                MessageBoxIcon ico = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
                DialogResult result;
                result = MessageBox.Show(this, msg, caption, buttons, ico);
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    generateautoID();
                    this.iP_SpoolsBindingSource.EndEdit();
                    MessageBox.Show("The Record saved Successfully:" + outputSpoolNoTextBox.Text, "Save_Update",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    this.iP_SpoolsTableAdapter.Update(this.sQCDataDataSet.IP_Spools);
                    this.iP_SpoolsTableAdapter.Fill(this.sQCDataDataSet.IP_Spools);
                    //MessageBox.Show("The Record saved Successfully:", "Save_Update",
                        //MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    this.iP_SpoolsBindingSource.AddNew();
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Saving Failed:" + ex.Message.ToString(), "Save",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }

        private void btncancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void TSCalc_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (unitComboBox.Text == "Mic")
                {
                    Decimal a = Decimal.Parse(frontWtTextBox.Text);
                    Decimal b = Decimal.Parse(backWtTextBox.Text);
                    Decimal c = (a + b) / 2;
                    Decimal d = Decimal.Parse(cFComboBox.Text);
                    Decimal g = (c * c)/d;
                    decimal h = decimal.Parse(bLTextBox.Text);
                    decimal j = h / g;
                    tSTextBox.Text = Decimal.Round(j, 2).ToString("0.00");
                }
                else if (unitComboBox.Text == "Mg")
                {
                    Decimal a = Decimal.Parse(frontWtTextBox.Text);
                    Decimal b = Decimal.Parse(backWtTextBox.Text);
                    Decimal c = (a + b) / 2;
                    Decimal h = decimal.Parse(bLTextBox.Text);
                    Decimal g = h / c;
                    tSTextBox.Text = Decimal.Round(g, 2).ToString("0.00");
                }
                else
                {
                    tSTextBox.Text = 0.ToString("0.00");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("TS Can't be calculated:Check All the boxes are entered" + ex.Message.ToString(), "TS Calculation",
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void getlotnumbers()
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                SqlCommand cmd;
                con.Open();
                string s = "SELECT t1.CoilNo FROM IP_Spools AS t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Lot_Numbers AS t2 ON t1.CoilNO = t2.CoilNumber";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                lotNoTextBox.Text = s;
                con.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Lot Number Not Found:" + ex.Message.ToString(), "Lot Number",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            
        }

        private void Svlinklabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (frontWtTextBox.Text != "" && backWtTextBox.Text != "")
                {
                    Decimal a = Decimal.Parse(frontWtTextBox.Text);
                    Decimal b = Decimal.Parse(backWtTextBox.Text);
                    Decimal c = 0;
                    if (a > b)
                    {
                        c = ((a - b) / b);
                        svTextBox.Text = Decimal.Round(c, 2).ToString("0.00");
                    }
                    else if (b > a)
                    {
                        c = ((b - a) / b);
                        svTextBox.Text = Decimal.Round(c, 2).ToString("0.00");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    svTextBox.Text = 0.ToString("0.00");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SV Calculation Failed:" + ex.Message.ToString(), "SV calculation",
                     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void LotNolinklabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            getlotnumbers();
        }
        private void generateautoID()
        {
            try
            {
                string customID = string.Empty;
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                customID = dt.ToString("yyyyMM");
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
                SqlCommand cmd;
                con.Open();
                string s = "select Max(SpoolId) from IP_Spools";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
                int count = Convert.ToInt16(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;
                con.Close();
                outputSpoolNoTextBox.Text = customID + count;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("AUTOID Error:" + ex.ToString(), "QCIP", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

image of winform design:

[image: winform]

Comment: what is the task accomplished by the code?

Comment: it'll enter the data to my mssql database when  above validations satisfy..

Comment: The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @RaviKumar The task is not "enter the data to my mssql database when above validations satisfy", that is a fairly generic description that could be applied to numerous questions here. Look at the other questions on this site and how they are titled.

Comment: ohh ok ..sorry i didn't knew ..what i am trying to ask is i have created some custom function and i have linked those function into the click events of my WinForms button...i needed to know the way i have written my functions are efficient? and is it readable for others too?. And is there any point where i need to focus on etc..

Comment: In the body question itself please state what the form is supposed to do. It looks like it might be an inventory of wires. The explanation will help us review the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what StyxRiver already said, a couple tips:

Potentially suspicious function:

```
generateautoID()
```

What does it *really* do ? I suspect this is a task that could be left to the DBMS you're using...

You have a routine `get_items` to populate a few combo boxes. Instead, I would load the list of options to a **datatable** and bind it to the combo box.
For this, use the `DataSource` and `DisplayMember` properties. In your case that would be something along these lines.
Assuming you already have a connection open and available (con):

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM table"))
{
    cmd.Connection = con;
    using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        // Create a new DataTable.
        DataTable dtReasons = new DataTable("Reasons");

        // Load results into the DataTable.
        dtReasons.Load(sdr);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
rejectReason1ComboBox.DataSource = the_datatable
rejectReason1ComboBox.DisplayMember = "column you want to show"
rejectReason1ComboBox.ValueMember = "underlying column value"
```

Note that there are different ways of doing the same thing, using SqlDataReader or something else.

Exception handling: it is present in multiple functions. This is OK for testing but I would recommend that you set up centralized exception handling **and logging** for your program. Define it once only.

But exception handling should not be used for **validation** of input, because it has a cost and is not optimal. Exception handling is meant to catch unexpected errors, not to serve as an all-purpose validation mechanism.

Checking that a text box is (not) empty is very simple, so you can easily prevent exceptions from being raised in the first place, and provide more meaningful feedback to the user. Saying that the calculation failed is **not helpful**. What is helpful and user-friendly is to state precisely what the error is, which fields are incomplete or incorrect. The exception handler as it is used lacks context.

Make sure that you use the right controls for your UI. For numeric input you should use [numericupdown controls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.numericupdown?view=net-5.0) instead of regular text boxes. That means the user is restricted as to what kind of input is allowed, and there is less validation effort on your end as a result. You will see that you can simplify your code further...

This code does not seem to be safe for your purpose:

```
if (frontWtTextBox.Text != "" && backWtTextBox.Text != "")
```

The text boxes could still contain garbage. But the numericupdown controls will alleviate this problem.

And since you have a grid layout, you might like the [tablelayoutpanel control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/step-4-lay-out-your-form-with-a-tablelayoutpanel-control?view=vs-2019). This will simplify your life if you have to make change to your form later...

Some superfluous imports (as far as I can tell but without testing the code):

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

I would get rid of unused imports and variables. Get rid of one-time variables as well, to keep the code as small as possible. Redundant/unused code is distraction.

In btnsave_Click you have code like this:

```
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
           ...
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
```

The else block is superfluous too, because this is the end of the procedure, there is nothing left to execute. So you can trim down the code a bit.

As already said the code could be more compact:

```
        String msg = "Confirm Save?";
        String caption = "Save Record";
        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.YesNo;
        MessageBoxIcon ico = MessageBoxIcon.Question;
        DialogResult result;
        result = MessageBox.Show(this, msg, caption, buttons, ico);
```

Only one line will suffice:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(this, "Confirm Save?", "Save Record", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

(you can still split this in two lines if you want)

You have too many variables, that makes the code unnecessarily longer and harder to follow. Good code should be intuitive and to the point.

Things to improve:

- naming conventions (for your own sanity) - variable names like a, b, c, d are a pain and it's not obvious what task is being performed, which leads me to the second point:
- commenting your code - when you have functions like `TSCalc_LinkClicked` it wouldn't hurt to write in a few lines what you are doing and why. If you revisit your code in 6 months you would have to reanalyze it.

Comment: Thank you very very much ...your inputs are so valuable for me as a learner ..will study on all the pints and i'll make the changes as you instructed..thank you again..

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the full intent of your task here, there are only a few generic suggestions I can offer:

1. **Avoid naming variables with single characters.** While that might feel like a slick or efficient thing to do, when things start getting complicated, you'll quickly regret that choice. You, or the poor soul after you. For example, your TSCalc_LinkClicked method would need a lot of variable renaming. Computers can handle whatever weird, slick code you throw at it, but you want it to be maintainable, so always remember that your maintainers are human. A handful of letter-sized variables is horrible to deal with when tracking down bugs. From a compiler's perspective, there's no difference whether the variable is named **a** or **thisIncrediblyDescriptiveButOverlyLongVariableName**, but your colleagues will thank you.
2. **Use Microsoft's coding standards if possible.** Those are largely considered industry standard, and state to use the implicitly typed variable (var) unless the type is not immediately obvious. I generally find most places follow (to some degree or another) this standard.
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions
3. **Avoid creating unnecessary variables.** An example would be the message and caption you have in btnsave_Click - they're only used in once and in one place in that method. There's no need to allocate a variable specifically for that purpose. This is super micro-optimization, but something to keep in mind is only create what is necessary when it is necessary. Keep your footprint small.
4. **Dispose of your connections.** Last suggestion, and the one I consider most important - you are not disposing your connections or commands, instead relying entirely on the GC to do that. Good practice suggests wrapping those in using statements. A benefit of wrapping those in using statements is that the commands are closed when you leave that exection block and dispose is called - no need to handle it explicitly, it's cleaned up appropriately. See below:

   ```
    using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "Your SQL Statement";

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
   ```

Another option is:

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                /* Do stuff with reader */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions ...as you said i was clearly ignorant on naming the variables but now i will give them all meaningful names, and i will handle sql connections and functions as per your instructions.